# ¿Como obtengo los valores de una lista al cerrar el formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, lista

Tengo dos formularios y una clase, en el formulario 1 al apretar un `radiobutton` se me abre un **formulario2** con `showdialog`, pero este **formulario1** permanece abierto, mientras que en el **formulario2** es en donde ingreso valores los cuales guardo en una lista al presionar un boton asi:

```
private List<RetencionG> GuardarRetencion()
    {            
        
        string numeroretencion = txtNumeroSerie1Comprobante.Text + txtNumeroSerie2Comprobante.Text + txtNumeroSecuencialComprobante.Text;
        string aut = txtAutRetencionV.Text.Trim();
        string fechaaut = FechaAutorizacion.Value.ToString();
        string acceso = txtAccesoRetencionV.Text.Trim();
        string tipocomprobante = dgvRetencion.CurrentRow.Cells["Comprobante"].Value.ToString();
        string numerocomprobante = dgvRetencion.CurrentRow.Cells["NumeroComprobante"].Value.ToString();
        string fechacomprobante = dgvRetencion.CurrentRow.Cells["Fecha"].Value.ToString();
        string ambiente = cmbAmbiente.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string emision = cmbEmision.SelectedValue.ToString();

        List<RetencionG> llena = new List<RetencionG>();
        RetencionG re = new RetencionG();
        
        re.Numeroretencion = numeroretencion;
        re.Cliente = idClienteF;
        re.Fecharetencion = FechaRetencion;
        re.Autorizacion = aut;
        re.Fechaaut = fechaaut;
        re.Acceso = acceso;
        re.Tipocomprobante = tipocomprobante;
        re.Numerocomprobante = numerocomprobante;
        re.Fecha = fechacomprobante;
        re.Ambiente = ambiente;
        re.Emision = emision;
        
        llena.Add(re);            
        return llena;}
```

Mi clase donde se encuentra la lista la tengo asi:

```
class RetencionG
{
    private string numeroretencion;
    private string cliente;
    private string fecharetencion;
    private string autorizacion;
    private string fechaaut;
    private string acceso;
    private string tipocomprobante;
    private string numerocomprobante;
    private string fecha;
    private string ambiente;
    private string emision;

    public string Numeroretencion
    {
        get { return numeroretencion; }
        set { numeroretencion = value; }
    }
    public string Cliente
    {
        get { return cliente; }
        set { cliente = value; }
    }
    public string Fecharetencion
    {
        get { return fecharetencion; }
        set { fecharetencion = value; }
    }
    public string Autorizacion
    {
        get { return autorizacion; }
        set { autorizacion = value; }
    }
    public string Fechaaut
    {
        get { return fechaaut; }
        set { fechaaut = value; }
    }
    public string Acceso
    {
        get { return acceso; }
        set { acceso = value; }
    }
    public string Tipocomprobante
    {
        get { return tipocomprobante; }
        set { tipocomprobante = value; }
    }
    public string Numerocomprobante
    {
        get { return numerocomprobante; }
        set { numerocomprobante = value; }
    }
    public string Fecha
    {
        get { return fecha; }
        set { fecha = value; }
    }
    public string Ambiente
    {
        get { return ambiente; }
        set { ambiente = value; }
    }
    public string Emision
    {
        get { return emision; }
        set { emision = value; }
    } }
```

Y antes de que se cierre el formulario hago un count de la lista para saber si tiene valores y el count me da 1. Al cerrarse este **formulario2** y quedarme en el **formulario1** tengo un boton en el cual guardare los datos de la lista en variables, para así guardarlas en la base de datos, y trato de acceder a la lista asi:

```
private void btnGuardarFact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                               
    List<RetencionG> listaR = new List<RetencionG>(); 
    listaR.ElementAt(1);  
                    
    MessageBox.Show(listaR.Count.ToString());                      
                        
 }
```

Pero antes de guardar accedo al count de la lista para saber si tengo datos y me sale count 0.
¿Como hago para que permanezcan los datos de esa lista al cerrar el **formulario2**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que utilizo en estos casos es crear una `Interface` que funcione como intermediario entre los dos formularios. Algunos beneficios de este patrón es que no agrega dependencias o acoplamientos y cada formulario puede ser modificado sin afectar al otro.

Con base en la interpretación que le doy a tu planteamiento será necesario lo siguiente:

- Definir una Interface con un método que será implementado en *formuario1*.
- Definir una variable en *formulario1* donde será asignada la lista que proviene de *formulario2*.
- Asignar la propiedad `Owner` a la instancia del *formulario2* antes de abrirlo.
- Identificar el bloque de código donde se cierra el *formulario2* porque ese es el lugar donde se asignará la lista al *formulario1*.

#### Definición de Interface

Puedes utilizar los nombres que consideres más convenientes.

```
public interface IListaDeRetencionG
{
    void AsignarLista(List<RetencionG> listaDeRetencion);
}
```

#### Cambios en formulario1

Aquí será necesario hacer lo siguiente:

- Modificar la declaración del formulario.
- Declarar e inicializar la variable donde será asignada la lista recibida del *formulario2*.
- Crear el método requerido por la interface (en este caso lo llamé `AsignarLista`)
- Asignar la propiedad `Owner` a la instancia del `formulario2` antes de abrirlo.

Ver más comentarios en el código

```
// La declaración del formulario1 deberia quedar similar a esta
// asumiendo que en realidad se llama Formulario1

public partial class Formulario1 : Form, IListaDeRetencionG
{
    // ...
    // Entre las variables que ya tienes declaradas
    // ...
    // Asegurate de tener una variable para asignar la lista recibida, 
    // puedes utilizar un nombre de tu conveniencia
    List<RetencionG> listaDeRetencionRecibida = new List<RetencionG>();

    // ...

    //Agregar este método para implementar la interface IListaDeRetencionG
    public void AsignarLista(List<RetencionG> listaDeRetencion)
    {
        //Sugiero validar que la lista recibida no sea nula
        if( listaDeRetencion != null )
        {
            listaDeRetencionRecibida = listaDeRetencion;
        }
    }


    // Debes asignar la propiedad Owner a la instancia de formulario2 antes de abrirlo.
    // De acuerdo con tu planteamiento, es posible que tengas algo similar esto
    private void radioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                                            //aqui se asigna la propiedad Owner
        var formulario2 = new Formulario2() { Owner = this };
        formulario2.ShowDialog();
    }        
}
```

#### Cambios en formulario2

En el método donde cierras el *formulario2*, la lista ya debería estar creada. Aunque me faltan detalles para darle precisión, el bloque de código siguiente te dará una idea de las instrucciones que debes agregar.
Se asume que la lista creada se encuentra en una variable llamada `listaResultado`.

```
private void metodoDondeCierrasElFormulario(...)
{
    // En este punto se asume que la lista ya está creada 
    // en la variable listaResultado
    IListaDeRetencionG owner = this.Owner as IListaDeRetencionG;
    if (owner != null)
    {
        owner.AsignarLista(listaResultado);
    }

    //...
    // Otras instrucciones que puedas tener en el cierre.
}
```

Asumiendo que el método que incluiste al final de tu pregunta forma parte del *formulario1*, allí no deberías crear una nueva instancia de la lista, solo deberías trabajar con la variable que recibe los datos del *formulario2* identificada en el código como `listaDeRetencionRecibida`

```
//Por ejemplo:

private void btnGuardarFact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                               
    MessageBox.Show(listaDeRetencionRecibida.Count.ToString());                      
}
```

Por favor hazme saber cualquier duda que se te presente con el código de mi respuesta y/o si requieres más detalles en alguna explicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono