# Acceder a un control en un fomulario desde otro

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, poo, visual-studio-2019

Tengo un formulario principal, el cual tiene un panel contenedor, y abre formularios dentro de ese panel, de modo que tengo un menu lateral fijo y segun pulse el boton se van abriendo formularios dentro del panel. El código para abrir un formulario es el siguiente:

```
  private void AbrirFormulario(Form FormularioHijo)
        {
            FormularioActual = FormularioHijo;
            FormularioHijo.TopLevel = false;
            FormularioHijo.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            FormularioHijo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            PanelContenedor.Controls.Add(FormularioHijo);
            PanelContenedor.Tag = FormularioHijo;            
            FormularioHijo.BringToFront();
            FormularioHijo.Show();
        }
```

Ahora bien, el formulario principal tiene un titulo que indica el titulo del formulario abierto, y además los botones que indican el form actual cambian de color hasta que se cierra. ¿Como puedo acceder a esos controles desde el formulario hijo? Quiero modificar un textbox y los colores del boton cuando este formulario se cierre. Ya probé muchas formas pero los ejemplos son con formularios que se abren en otra ventana. ¿cual seria la meejor manera de hacerlo con base en el procedimiento empleado de formularios dentro de paneles?

Comment: Quieres modificar un `TextBoxt` que está dentro del form que abres dentro del panel?, El botón al que quieres cambiar el color es el botón que se encuentra en el formulario principal?, si es asi puedes usar el evento `ControlRemoved` del `Panel` ahí el parámetro `sender` convertirlo a `Form` y de este modo obtendrás todas las propiedades del Form que se esta cerrando, y ya se sea por el Caption o Name del Form, puedes identificar a que botón cambiar el color. `Form myform = sender as Form();
if (myform.Text.Equals(AlgunBoton.Text)) AlgunBoton.BackColor = tuColor;` Solo es una idea...

Comment: Rafael, en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/373058/182188) encontrarás una idea que funciona para estos casos.